Photoshop Video Animation Timeline: Frame durations don't line up
I noticed that oftentimes when I'm doing animations in Photoshop using the timeline, the frames don't line up and I have to readjust them. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if there is an option I missed. In the video below, I'm trying to make both frames have a duration of 2 seconds. However, they are clearly different in length. What is causing this?
https://streamable.com/r6e2vy


Do both have the same frame rate?

Yes, it's the same frame rate.

Do they have the same number of frames?
